# How to pause a release pipeline to wait until scheduled time in ServiceNow?

Tags: azure-devops

How do I pause a Azure DevOps release pipeline to stop executing until scheduled time is reached in ServiceNow?

I was trying to setup something in Predeployment gates but I am not successful. Please help me with an idea and program to achieve it.

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the suggestion below? May I know if it could meet your requirement? Thx.

Comment: Hi @Enig, If the suggestions works for you, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), which may help others with similar concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are seeking the feature to check [business hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#business-hours) before running a deployment in a release pipeline. This is supported out of the box with [deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) in **YAML** pipelines, which can run against [environments with approvals/checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass).

However for a classic release pipeline, there is no such equivalent feature as of now.

If you would prefer to use the classic release pipeline for your deployment, you may consider leveraging the marketplace extension [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) to trigger a YAML build during a release, where a `deployment` job is referencing its `environment` that is enabled with business hours check. Take the workaround steps below for example.

1. Install the extension [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks), which includes the tasks of `TriggerBuild` and `WaitForBuildToFinish`;
2. In the same stage of the actual job for deployment, add a dependency job in front of it; it is suggested to use a **self-hosted** agent pool for the dependency job to check business hours, because it may take quite a long time for the YAML pipeline build to complete and Microsoft-hosted parallel jobs have [time limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#timeouts), while self-hosted parallel jobs don't;
   [image]
3. In the dependency job, add the tasks `TriggerBuild` and `WaitForBuildToFinish`;
   [image]
4. Create the YAML pipeline to be triggered with the name `CheckBusinessHours`;

   ```
   trigger: none
   pool:
     vmImage: ubuntu-latest
   jobs:
   - deployment: CheckBusinessHours
     environment: E-BusinessHours
     strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
         steps:
         - script: echo Checking Business Hours -- Passed.
   ```
5. Set `security` policy of the YAML pipeline to `Allow` the **corresponding** pipeline service account to `Queue builds` according to your job authorization scope;
   [image]
6. Add `Business hours` check for the environment `E-BusinessHours`;
   [image]
7. When a new release is created, the dependency job will trigger the YAML pipeline to check business hours; the YAML pipeline will not be running until the business hours check has passed; the task `WaitForBuildToFinish` will periodically detect the status of this YAML pipeline build; once the build is succeeded, then the subsequent job in the stage of the release pipeline starts to run;
   [image]
8. Please make sure you have sufficient parallel jobs, since the workaround may consume 2 parallel jobs at the same time.

Still, this is simply a workaround. If you would consider using YAML pipeline directly, it will save many efforts. Hope the suggestion could help.